# Async load options to selectbox - dont show select

Tags: angular

I created an Angular 2 component for async loading options to `selectbox` :

**HTML**

```
<select (click)="onClickHandler()" [(ngModel)]="value" [class]="'form-control'">
    <ng-container *ngIf="options">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let option of options">
            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: {$implicit: option}">
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
function onClickHandler() {
    if (this.enableCache && this.options) {
        return;
    }

    this.http.get(...).subscribe(response => this.options = response['value']);

    // options contains this : [
    //     {value: 'Not_started' },
    //     { Value: 'New' },
    //     { Value: 'In Progress' },
    //     { Value: 'Done' }
    // ]
}
```

I have a problem with opening `selectbox`. When I click to select, don't open options, here is result:
[image]

When I would like to show all options, I must close select and open again.
I noticed, when I remove `class="form-control"` it works correctly.
When can be problem? Thanks for advices.

Comment: can you show options values ? update options array in this question

Comment: I updated my question. Is that what you thought? I added options data structure

Comment: use `*ngIf` and remove it from DOM

Comment: Can you show me how to do?

Comment: can you create a plunker @bluray